# How to make the window object available to Pug?

Tags: javascript, html, express, templates, pug

I like the simplicity of Pug, but sometimes it behaves erratically, and it's tough to distill what's the problem. I'm using Node, Express, and Pug (aka Jade), and I need to append my URL (window.local.href) to a string. **I can't get Pug to access window.local.href**

I have read about its interpolation, searched on GitHub for Pug files and here in SO. Still can't make it display in an href attribute the current URL.
I have successfully used variables in several templates within y project, sometimes after a few trial and error.

But here I'm stuck. Trying to brute force my way out of this:

```js
    script.
        currentURL = window.location.href
        console.log(currentURL) // Works as expected
        console.log(window.location.href) // Works as expected

    pre= currentURL // undefined
    pre= window.location.href // error because everything is undefined
    input.sample(type='button', value="alert href", onclick="alert(window.location.href)") // Works as expected
```

Also went through (just in case):

```
a(href = 'https://url-to-append-it-to.com/?status=!{window.location.href}')
a(href = 'https://url-to-append-it-to.com/?status=#{window.location.href}')
a(href = 'https://url-to-append-it-to.com/?status=${window.location.href}')
a(href = `https://url-to-append-it-to.com/?status=${currentURL}`)
a(href = `https://url-to-append-it-to.com/?status=#{window.location.href}`)
a(href = `https://url-to-append-it-to.com/?status=!{window.location.href}`)
```

And also (one by one):

```
- currentURL = window.location.href // Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

a(href=${window.location.href}) // Unexpected token
a(href=#{window.location.href}) // Unexpected character '#'
a(href=window.location.href) // Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
a(href=${currentURL}) // Unexpected token
a(href=#{currentURL}) // Unexpected character '#'
a(href=currentURL) // links to undefined
a(href=${window.location.href}) // Unexpected token
```

I have also tried to attach `window.location.href` to something like `locals.currentURL` with no luck.

For now, I've decided to pass down from the routes file: `currentLocation: req.protocol + "://" + req.headers.host + req.url` and use it as follows:

```
a(href= `https://url-to-append-it-to.com/?status=${currentLocation}`)
```

This works great, but I want to know what am I missing when trying to request local browser variables from Pug.

I assume the script tags do run on the client-side when pug has been rendered, but maybe the variables I'm having problems with are trying run halfway in rendering? I don't know.

Comment: can you show how you render the pug?

Answer (score 4):

The Pug template compilation (and therefore interpolation) is not executed within the scope of the DOM, so it has no idea what "window", "document", and "location" are. Contrast this with the content of your script tag, which is executed by the browser, not by node. Luckily, the request object also has the information you want, and we can pass it to Pug.

Assuming you are using Express Router, when you call render, you can pass parameters like:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('/', { currentURL: req.url });
});
```

Other options on the request object include req.originalUrl, req.baseUrl, req.route.path, and req.query (which is an object automatically built from the query string parameters).